# Discord.py if statements for some reason will not work..?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So, I have the following code.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def tip(ctx, amount: int, other: discord.Member):
    id = ctx.message.author.id
    other_id = other.id
    if id in ids:
        maddy = block_io.get_address_balance(label=id)
        oaddy = block_io.get_address_balance(label=other_id)
        s1 = json.dumps(maddy)
        d2 = json.loads(s1)
        s2 = json.dumps(oaddy)
        d3 = json.loads(s2)
        d2['data']['available_balance']
        d3['data']['available_balance']

        if float(d2['data']['available_balance']) > amount:
            if amount > 2:
                embed=discord.Embed(description="Tip Sent! **-1 Fee Deducted**", color=0x00ff00)
                await client.say(embed=embed)
                block_io.withdraw_from_labels(amounts=amount, from_labels=id, to_labels=other_id)
            else:
                embed=discord.Embed(description="Tipping requires you to have at least 2 Doge. **1 is deducted for fees.**", color=0x00ff00)
                await client.say(embed=embed)

            #embed=discord.Embed(description="", color=0x00ff00)
            #await client.say(embed=embed)
        else: #less then 
            embed=discord.Embed(description="**You dont have enough to tip!**", color=0x00ff00)
            await client.say(embed=embed)
            with open("ids.txt", "a") as f:
                print(id, file=f)
    else:
        block_io.get_new_address(label=id)
        block_io.get_address_balance(label=id)
        maddy = block_io.get_address_balance(label=id)
        oaddy = block_io.get_address_balance(label=other_id)
        s1 = json.dumps(maddy)
        d2 = json.loads(s1)
        s2 = json.dumps(oaddy)
        d3 = json.loads(s2)
        d2['data']['available_balance']
        d3['data']['available_balance']

        if float(d2['data']['available_balance']) > amount:
            if amount > 2:
                embed=discord.Embed(description="Tip Sent! **-1 Fee Deducted**", color=0x00ff00)
                await client.say(embed=embed)
                block_io.withdraw_from_labels(amounts=amount, from_labels=id, to_labels=other_id)
            else:
                embed=discord.Embed(description="Tipping requires you to have at least 2 Doge. **1 is deducted for fees.**", color=0x00ff00)
                await client.say(embed=embed)

            #embed=discord.Embed(description="", color=0x00ff00)
            #await client.say(embed=embed)
        else: #less then 
            embed=discord.Embed(description="**You dont have enough to tip!**", color=0x00ff00)
            await client.say(embed=embed)
            with open("ids.txt", "a") as f:
                print(id, file=f)
    with open("ids.txt", "a") as f:
        print(id, file=f)
```

When I run the command, I try and tip someone who does not have a account. Yet, instead of doing the else statement, it just goes to the if statement, and produces the error. I want it to goto the else statement, but it won't even though the users id is not in ids.

```
Ignoring exception in command tip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 50, in wrapped
    ret = yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "index.py", line 89, in tip
    oaddy = block_io.get_address_balance(label=other_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/block_io/__init__.py", line 168, in hook
    return self.api_call(attr, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/block_io/__init__.py", line 290, in api_call
    raise BlockIoAPIError('Failed: '+response['data']['error_message'])
block_io.BlockIoAPIError: Failed: One or more addresses or labels do not exist on your account for Network=DOGE, or are invalid for Network=DOGE.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 846, in process_commands
    yield from command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 374, in invoke
    yield from injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 54, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: BlockIoAPIError: Failed: One or more addresses or labels do not exist on your account for Network=DOGE, or are invalid for Network=DOGE.
Ignoring exception in command tip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 50, in wrapped
    ret = yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "index.py", line 89, in tip
    oaddy = block_io.get_address_balance(label=other_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/block_io/__init__.py", line 168, in hook
    return self.api_call(attr, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/block_io/__init__.py", line 290, in api_call
    raise BlockIoAPIError('Failed: '+response['data']['error_message'])
block_io.BlockIoAPIError: Failed: One or more addresses or labels do not exist on your account for Network=DOGE, or are invalid for Network=DOGE.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 846, in process_commands
    yield from command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 374, in invoke
    yield from injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 54, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: BlockIoAPIError: Failed: One or more addresses or labels do not exist on your account for Network=DOGE, or are invalid for Network=DOGE.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't spam text just to pad your question!

Answer (score 0):

This is the line that is failing:

```
oaddy = block_io.get_address_balance(label=other_id)
```

Note that this is present in both your `if` and `else` blocks.  You don't have any logic about what to do if the *other* person doesn't have an account, only if the person invoking the command doesn't have an account.  You'll need to check `if other_id in ids:` at some point.

Comment: other.id? SCAM?

Comment: @Zatbot I don't understand the question

Comment: is it other.id?

Comment: Is what `other.id`?

Comment: instead of other_id is it other.id

Comment: It doesn't matter.  You have `other_id = other.id`, so those are the same value.

Comment: ok https://hastebin.com/royuwatazo.coffeescript can you see this and see if u can fix?

Comment: It's the same problem.  You're calling `block_io.get_address_balance` without checking if they have an account.  If you're having trouble, maybe change your approach from checking against stored `id`s.  Instead you could simply catch the error that is being raised by that line and use that to fail gracefully.

Comment: is that the only issue